# Why is a negative index value taken while inserting a new element into an java array?

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I was trying out a java code to insert a new element into an array, I understand most of the program except for a line of code: "int newindex = -index-1;". Why does a negative sign used in front of the index?

Here is the full program:

```
public class ArrayManipulation2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] array = {6,3,5,2,-9,-5,-1,0};
        Arrays.sort(array);
        printArray(array);

        int index= Arrays.binarySearch(array, 1);
        int newindex = -index-1;

        array = insertElement(array, 1, newindex);
        printArray(array);
    }


    public static void printArray(int[] array){

        for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++){
            if(i!=0){
                System.out.print(", ");
            }
            System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    public static int[] insertElement(int[] orginal, int element, int index){
        int length = orginal.length;
        int[] destination = new int[length+1];
        System.arraycopy(orginal, 0, destination, 0, index);
        destination[index]=element;
        System.arraycopy(orginal, index, destination, index+1, length-index);

        return destination;

    }
}
```

I need to know why the new index is specified as "-index-1"?.

Comment: That does seem weird. Are you sure the code works? If it works, there should be a comment on whatever clever indexing trick this is.

Comment: I think this only works because `1` is not even in the array, so the "index" will be -1, and the `newindex` becomes `0`. Probably just (bad) sample code.

Comment: As per javadocs *index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) - 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.*

Comment: When i removed the negative index value, i got the " Index out of Bound Exception". Unfortunately there was no comments for explaining  the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Arrays.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) returns a negative value if the item isn't already in the array, so that it can distinguish between where the item is if it is there and where it should be if it isn't there.

The code isn't correct without catering for the case where the result is positive.

Answer (score 0):

Background:

The method [`Arrays.binarySearch()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-) returns

> the index of the search key, if it is contained in the array; otherwise, (-(insertion point) – 1). The insertion point is defined as the point at which the key would be inserted into the array: the index of the first element greater than the key, or a.length if all elements in the array are less than the specified key. Note that this guarantees that the return value will be >= 0 if and only if the key is found.

So, this API suggested be used in a sorted array, otherwise it could return unexpected return value

Then ,let me clarify the code :
If can not find the element, the method will return value "(-(insertion point) – 1)" , then get its "opposite number",so the value could be insertion+1, and then minus 1， we can get its right insert position

Comment: Use quote formatting for text that is quoted, and cite your sources.

Comment: Still not complete because you stil haven't cited your [source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-int:A-int-). Does it really take 20 minutes to complete your answer?

Comment: @EJP,  you are right ,its my fault, but it not due to I take 20 minutes to complete my answer, but due to I ought to not post my answer before fully check it!